# postgres access a cte inside a view

Tags: sql, postgresql

is it possible, in postgresql - to access a cte defined in a view?
By that I mean - if you have the following:

```sql
create view my_view as 
with
    blah as (select 1 as x, 2 as y, 3 as z)
select
    x*x as x_squared,
    y*y as y_squared,
    z*z as z_squared
from
    blah
```

is there any way from outside of getting at blah?   eg looking for something like:

```sql
select * from my_view.blah
```

Basically we have large views that use a number of complicated CTE's - and it's quite difficult sometimes to troubleshoot them without splitting them all out into separate smaller views [yes, I would prefer to just keep it like that, but I don't have that option]

I know I will be able to do it by making a stored proc that pulls out the view definition - extracts the with clauses, parses up to the blah definition, changes that to the main select, gets rid of the rest, and then does the query - but that all seems like a lot of work.   Am hoping there's a built-in way?

Comment: No, this is not possible.  A view encapsulates the entire query. If you want the CTE separately, then use a separate view for that.

Comment: Nope. That's an internal structure of the view. But... you can create a new view for `blah` if you need to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok - so I have a sort of solution - it's a not a function - it's a procedure that turns a cte into a materialized_view.

I first wanted to formulate it as function, so you could say:

```sql
select * from cte_from( 'my_real_view', 'the_cte' )
```

but it appears that a function needs its schema defined in advance, which is obviously impossible in this case.  If anyone can suggest a hack to make it closer to above, I'd apperciate it.  But anyway - bottom line this works:

```sql
create procedure from_cte(view_schema text, view_name text, cte_name text, materialized_view_name text) as
$func$
declare
    _code   text;
    _others text;
    _script text;
begin
    execute format('drop materialized view if exists %s', materialized_view_name);
    with recursive
        string_provider as (
            select view_definition as the_string,
                   position(concat(cte_name, ' as (') in lower(view_definition)) + length(cte_name) + 5 as start_location
            from information_schema.views
            where table_name = view_name
              and table_schema = view_schema
        ),
        string_walk as (
            select start_location as x,
                   1              as brackets
            from string_provider
            union
            select x + 1,
                   new_brackets
            from string_provider,
                 string_walk,
                 lateral (select case
                                     when substring(the_string from x + 1 for 1) = '(' then brackets + 1
                                     when substring(the_string from x + 1 for 1) = ')' then brackets - 1
                                     else brackets
                                     end as new_brackets
                     ) calculated
            where new_brackets != 0
              and x < length(the_string)
        )
    select substring(the_string from start_location for 1 + max(x) - start_location),
           trim(substring(the_string from 0 for start_location - length(cte_name) - 5))
    into _code, _others
    from string_walk,
         string_provider
    group by the_string, start_location;

    if length(_others) < 5 then
        select _code into _script;
    else
        select concat(substring(_others from 0 for length(_others)), ' ', _script) into _script;
    end if;
    execute format('create materialized view %s as ( %s )', materialized_view_name, _code);
end
$func$ language plpgsql;
```

Comment: actually - got it fully working in the from_cte as a function using return setof record - but that's annoying because then when you use it - you have to put in the field types :(

Answer (score 0):

You can create the CTE as a view by itself. For example:

```
create table a (b int);

insert into a (b) values (1), (50), (200), (350), (1000);

create view blah as 
select * from a where b > 100;
```

Anf then base your original view on this new intermediate one to avoid repeating code:

```
create view my_view as 
select * from blah where b < 500;
```

See running example at [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6vvu88SqSHU6KSwCC81Xc9/0).

Comment: That's the way to go. But be careful: in my experience, if you define views on views, you'll soon cease to understand your queries.